# Sharepoint Webaprt

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, web-services, ajax

How to call sharepoint webpart usercontrol method in AJAX

```
$.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "FundUserRegister2.asmx\validateEmail",

                data: "{'strMailID': '" + $('#<%= txtEmail.ClientID %>').val() + "'}",

                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                dataType: "json",

                success: function (message) {


                    alert(message.d);

                }, error: function (message) {


                    alert(message.d);
                }
            });
```

method is as following

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string validateEmail(string strMailID)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strMailID))
            {
                string pwdRandom = DateTime.Now.ToString("htffffsH");

                MembershipCreateStatus status;
                MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(strMailID, pwdRandom, strMailID, null, null, false, out status);
                if (status == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
                    return "true";
                else
                    return "false";
            }
            else
            {
                return "false";
            }
```

Comment: May I know why you want to get user control in ajax

Comment: to check dynamically weather user exist in database